# Determine underlying calls triggered by Windows GUI action

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-7, event-log

This is a follow-up question to one I asked on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/q/909629/224812).
How can I trace the consequences of GUI actions. Is there some kind of low level event log in windows?

**Example**
If the user double-clicks on `<name>.pdf`, the consequences are:

- the extension is determined,
- the full path is determined
- the file is opened with the program associated with given extension

at least I assume that is what happens. That are the consequences I want to track in order to reproduce them in code.

Comment: [Event Tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803.aspx) is the system-wide infrastructure to generate logs. It is useful for diagnostics, and not so useful for reverse-engineering. From your question it appears that you assume whatever is happening is simple and straight forward. In reality, it isn't. More importantly, you seem to be after a way to automate a UI, by observing and replaying actions in code. Use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) instead. It's the non-hacky solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no log that you can examine in order to reproduce events and behaviour of the shell.

In this case, a double click results in the default verb being applied to the selected shell item. In code you are provided with the `ShellExecuteEx` function to do that.

Comment: What do you mean with 'shell item'? I want reproduce behaviour of the GUI, so I want to examine the actions applied to an GUI item.

Comment: A shell item is something like a file or a folder. There are other types of shell item. Use the function I referred to to invoke the default verb on your chosen shell item.